# Where do I find the customer ID in a Magento 2 database?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm using the CreativeMinds Multi User Accounts plugin.  In the `cminds_multiuseraccounts_subaccount` table it references `customer_id` and `parent_customer_id`.    Where is the `customer_id` defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can find customer id in 'customer_entity' Table

[image]